# Convergence of series with $\ln^3$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

How to prove that $\sum \frac {1}{(n+3)\ln^ 3 (n+3)} $ converges?

Comment: Integral test will do it.

Comment: The [Cauchy Condensation test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyCondensationTest.html) will work to.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563446/on-convergence-of-bertrand-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as David pointed out:

$$\int\limits_1^\infty\frac1{(x+3)\log^3(x+3)}dx=\left.-\frac12\frac1{\log^2(x+3)}\right|_1^\infty=\frac12\frac1{\log^24}=\frac18\frac1{\log^22}$$

and thus our series is convergente, **or** by the Condensation Test:

$$\frac{2^n}{(2^n+3)\log^3(2^n+3)}\le\frac1{n^3\log^32}$$

and since the series with general term $\;n^{-3}\;$ converges so does ours.

Comment: I think as in the title, the OP wanted the integral version. +1

Answer (score 4):

The [Bertrand series](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html) 
$$\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{1}{n^\alpha\ln^\beta n}$$
is convergent if and only if $(\alpha>1)\lor(\alpha=1\land\beta>1).$