# On convergence of Bertrand series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\ln^{\beta}(n)}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Study the convergence of $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}
>  \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\ln^{\beta}(n)}$$ where $\alpha, \beta \in
>  \mathbb{R}$

I have proved that:

1. This series diverges when $\alpha \leq 0$.
2. This series converges when $\alpha > 1, \beta > 0$
3. This series diverges when $0 < \alpha < 1, \beta > 0$
4. This series converges when $\alpha = 1, \beta > 1$

> **Question:** What happens when $\alpha > 0$ and $ \beta < 0$?

There are other questions on MSE which ask about this series, but this question is distinct because

- I would like an argument which does not rely on the integral test for series convergence, and
- this question considers all real $\alpha$ and $\beta$, while other questions ask only about $\alpha, \beta > 0$, where we can apply Cauchy condensation criterion

Comment: The Cauchy Condensation test works (in fact, this is sort of the canonical example of when to use the Cauchy Condensation test). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: And @User8128 how would I show that the sequence of terms is decreasing? (otherwise I can't apply that criterion)

Comment: It's clear the the terms are decreasing if you believe that $n^\alpha \ln^\beta(n)$ is increasing (which seems obvious enough that it can be stated without justification).

Comment: This doesn't seem obvious to me, since $\ln^{\beta}$ is decreasing for negative $\beta$

Comment: But $n^\alpha$ grows faster than $\ln^\beta(n)$ decreases  (this is the classical result that $n^\epsilon \gg \ln^k(n)$ for any $\epsilon, k > 0$)

Comment: I suppose in the case that $\alpha > 1$ or $\alpha < 1$, you don't even need the condensation test, you can show convergence\divergence by comparison with $1/n^{\alpha \pm \delta}$ for sufficiently small $\delta$. When $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta \le 0$, you can show divergence by comparison with $1/n$. Then we are in the case when $\alpha =1$ and $\beta > 0$ whence it is obvious that the terms decrease and you can apply the condensation test.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264767/infinite-sum-of-dfrac1np-lnnq

Answer (score 1):

In that last case it diverges those are [Bertrand's series see here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand):
indeed we have

$$\frac{1}{n^{\alpha/2}\ln^\beta n} =\left[\frac{1}{\frac{2\beta}{\alpha}n^{\alpha/2\beta}\ln n^{\alpha/2\beta}}\right]^{\beta}\to \left[\frac{1}{\frac{2\beta}{\alpha}0^-}\right]^{\beta} =\infty $$
Since if  $\alpha<0$ and $\beta>0$ then,  $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\alpha/2\beta}=0\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\alpha/2\beta}\ln n^{\alpha/2\beta} =0^-$$

Then there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ we have

$$\frac{1}{n^{\alpha/2}\ln^\beta n}>1\implies \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\ln^\beta n}>n^{-\alpha/2}$$
That is $$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\ln^\beta n}>\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}n^{-\alpha/2} =\infty$$
from this you get the divergence

Comment: And how would I show the case $\alpha < 0, \beta > 0$?

Comment: @Math_QED see the edit relaod your page

Comment: Moreover, if $\alpha =1, \beta > 0$, we have: the series $\sum \frac{1}{n\ln^{\beta}(n)}$ and by cauchy's condensation criterion, we get $\sum \frac{1}{\ln^{\beta}(2) n}$ which diverges, but in the comments and sources on the internet it should converge for $\beta  > 1$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: in that case it converges was that part of your question?

Comment: I accidentally pressed enter too early.

Comment: Nevermind I made a calculation error.

Comment: @Math_QED I added detailes computations