# Convergence of a series through comparison test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove that this series converge through comparison test.

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\log(1+n)}{n^2}$$

The problem is that I can't find a series to compare.

For example:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\log(1+n)}{n^2}>\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: Does $$\log(1+n)<n^{1/2}\space for\space large\space n$$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563446/on-convergence-of-bertrand-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha

Comment: You have identified that this is more "subtle" than $1/n^2$, but that's kind of the point of such an exercise.  Push on!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln y < y$ , letting $y=x^s$, We have  $$\ln (x^s) < x^s  $$

$$\implies \log x < \frac{x^s}{s} \; \forall s \in \Bbb R^+ $$

---

For $s=\frac 12$ , we get $$\log n <2\sqrt n \implies \log (n+1) < 2\sqrt{n+1}$$

Therefore $$\sum \frac{\log (1+n)}{n^2} < \sum \frac{ 2\sqrt {n+1}}{n^2} \sim_\infty \frac{2}{n^{3/2}} $$

Now since $\frac{2}{n^{3/2}} =2\zeta \left( \frac 32 \right) $ and $\zeta (s) $ converges for all $s >1$, $\displaystyle \sum \frac{\log (1+n)}{n^2} $ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to compare by limit comparison test with

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^{\frac32}}$$

or more in general with

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^{a}}$$

with $1<a<2$.

Answer (score 0):

By comparison test we have $$\frac{n^{3/2}\log (n)}{n^2}= \frac{\log (n)}{n^{1/2}} =\left(\frac{\log (n)}{n^{1/2}}\right)=2\frac{\log (n^{1/2})}{n^{1/2}}\to 0$$ that is for n large enough we have

$$\frac{\log (n)}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

the convergence follow by Riemann series. see more general here  [On convergence of Bertrand series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\ln^{\beta}(n)}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563446/on-convergence-of-bertrand-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the logarithm grows slower than all positive powers: $$\log n=o(n^\alpha), \alpha>0.$$

Indeed, when you increase $n$ geometrically, the LHS grows like an arithmetic sequence, while the RHS like a geometric one.

Then your general term can be bounded by some $n^{\alpha-2}<n^{-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{1}^{1+n}x^{-1/2}dx = $

$2(n+1)^{1/2} -2(1^{1/2})< 2(n+1)^{1/2} $.

Also we have:

$2(n+1)^{1/2} > \int_{1}^{1+n}(1/x^{1/2})dx \gt$

$ \int_{1}^{1+n}(1/x) dx = \ln(1+n)$.

Hence:

$2(n+1)^{1/2} \gt \ln(1+n)$.

Ready for the comparison test.